# How can I make an alias that automatically logs into a different user's iDisk?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, mobileme

I have an alias to a folder on another user's iDisk. When I opened it under Leopard it would automatically log me in to their iDisk and mount it, as I have the account information in my keychain.

However under Snow Leopard it instead brings up the dialog for a user/pass for the idisk.me.com domain. If use my user/pass it fails, if I use their user/pass it works.

My best guess is that since I have multiple keychain entries for the idisk.me.com domain, the alias isn't specific enough. But it did work under Leopard so I'm hoping there's a new way to make it work again under Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AppleScript Editor, enter the following code:

```
mount volume "http://username@idisk.mac.com/username/"  --replace username with the MobileMe name of the iDisk you're trying to connect to
```

Save the item as an Application if you want to open it from the Dock or Finder, or as a script if you want to launch it from the AppleScript menu.

I only have one MobileMe account to test, so I hope it's enough for Keychain to pick out the different versions.